# Django fails to connect to remote MongoDB server using djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

I try to connect to use a MongoDB database for the Django project.

So I follow a tutorial for changing the DATABASE from settings.py

```
# Original
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'testDB',
}
```

Changed to

```
# From tutorials
 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'djongo',
         'NAME': 'testDB',
         'USERNAME': 'username',
         'PASSWORD': 'password',
         'HOST': 'myhostname.example',
         'PORT': '27017',
     }
 }
```

Trying to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

All works, but no data in my database

Apparently django went for the localhost:27017 host and created a database there.

Uninstalling MongoDB, just caused makemigrations to fail

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I found a solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244703/7637454

To fulfill the answer here this is how you're supposed to configure it now.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {  
    'ENGINE':   'djongo',
    'NAME':     'yourmongodb',
    'CLIENT': {
      'host': 'some-host.or.ip',
      'port': 27017,
      'username': 'youruser',
      'password': 'yourdbpass',
      'authSource': 'yourcollection', # usually admin
    } 
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: sorry, pressed enter wrongly before finishing the post.

Comment: you answer worked for me - you should answer your own question and mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided, does not work for me, instead I adopted following approach.

So, behind the scene, the **Djongo** uses **PyMongo** and PyMongo's default configuration are:

```py
class MongoClient(common.BaseObject):
    HOST = "localhost"   # here HOST has the hardcoded value
    PORT = 27017
```

which are in the following file:

`venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py`

replace the harcoded value of `HOST` to something like

```py
HOST = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster-name/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Additionally, we can set the environment variable if we want

```py
HOST = os.getenv('MONGO_DB_URL')
```